# Is there a way to boost the speed of Ti.UI.TableView in Titanium for custom rows?

Tags: iphone, uitableview, performance, titanium

I'm using Titanium's appcelerator. I've seen the kitchensink example for tableView performance, but that's just for un-customized rows, at around 4ms a row on my 1G iPhone. The performance for 1.4.0 and 1.4.1.1 shoots up considerably when you have custom rows, like one with a picture and a label, to about 20ms per row at the very least.  For about 250 rows, it's been taking about 4-6 seconds.

Is there a way to boost the speed of displaying rows in the tableView? I remember reading that it use to be faster in 1.3.2. Will it get faster in 1.5.0?

Answer (score 0):

Check out the latest source. It is helpful in my case.
[Link](https://github.com/appcelerator/titanium_mobile/commit/1a5206fb3ba3617d052593c68e5eec753d47dd64#diff-2)